# SQL view must return executable strings including comma of fields

Tags: database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Business rule - need to create view which gets all values (or some of them) form table fields into one string / varchar field.
And than I would be possible to copy thees values to other environment.

Simple example (actually using 30+ fields):

```
id          int (autoincrement);
indicator   int
name        varchar
description varchar
relevance   varchar
object_fk   int
```

Some fields could be empty.

```
SELECT
  'INSERT INTO [DM_meta].[dbo].[measure] (
    id, indicator, name, description, relevance, object_fk
  )
  VALUES ('
    + CAST(id AS varchar(20)) + ', '
    + ISNULL(indicator,'NULL') + ', '
    + ISNULL(name,'NULL') + ', '
    + ISNULL(description,'NULL') + ', '
    + ISNULL(relevance,'NULL') + ', '
    + ISNULL(CAST(object_fk AS varchar(20)),'NULL')
    + ');
    ' AS _long_strings_to_coply_later_
FROM
  [DM_meta].[dbo].[measure]
```

For the look of one expected result is fine, except description field with dots and commas:

> INSERT INTO [DM_meta].dbo.measure ( id, indicator, name, description,
>   relevance, object_fk) VALUES ( 1103, NULL, NULL, **1.8.8.3. Lorem ipsum, where something, something and more**, Yes, 70);

So the question is - how to make description field in one string without comma delimitation and dot syntax error causing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the target environment is a SQL Server database, you have to format your output to provide valid SQL statements.

In T-SQL strings are quoted by the single quote character (`'`) You have to quote the strings in your output rows.

**Example**

```
SELECT
  '''' + name + ''''
FROM
  [DM_meta].[dbo].[measure]
```

It is possible, that the original string contains quotation marks. You have to escape those quotation marks:

```
SELECT
  '''' + REPLACE(name, '''', '''''') + ''''
FROM
  [DM_meta].[dbo].[measure]
```

In T-SQL you can escape the single quotation mark by doubling it. Run this statement to understand how escaping works:

```
SELECT
  '''' AS OneQuotation,
  '''''' AS TwoQuotations
```

Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT
  'INSERT INTO [DM_meta].[dbo].[measure] (
    id, indicator, name, description, relevance, object_fk
  )
  VALUES ('
    + CAST(id AS varchar(20)) + ', '
    + ISNULL(indicator,'NULL') + ', '
    + ISNULL('''' + REPLACE(name, '''', '''''') + '''','NULL') + ', '
    + ISNULL('''' + REPLACE(description, '''', '''''') + '''','NULL') + ', '
    + ISNULL('''' + REPLACE(relevance, '''', '''''') + '''','NULL') + ', '
    + ISNULL('''' + REPLACE(CAST(object_fk AS varchar(20)), '''', '''''') + '''','NULL')
    + ');
    ' AS _long_strings_to_coply_later_
FROM
  [DM_meta].[dbo].[measure]
```

**Additional notes**

Please note, that if your destination environment is a database server, you could use [Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) to transfer data from one server to another.

If Linked Server is not an option, please consider to use SSIS ([SQL Server Integration Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)) to generate or process files.

Comment: @Ilvars (and Pred): another option to easily move data from one server to another, if Linked Servers and/or SSIS are either unavailable or undesirable, is the `DB_BulkCopy` proc in the SQL# library. SQL# (SQLsharp) is a library of SQLCLR functions/procs that I wrote, and while not entirely free, the `DB_BulkCopy` proc is in the Free version, available at: http://www.SQLsharp.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the value in quotes..

try replacing *ISNULL(description,'NULL')* 
by char(39) + ISNULL(description,'NULL')+ char(39) or '''' + ISNULL(description,'NULL')+ ''''